# Spring Stream AggregateApplication with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to configure the ServletInitializer to run a Spring Stream Aggreagate Application within a tomcat host with WAR packaging. The parent app is configured as...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyAggregateApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        AggregateApplication aggregateApp = new AggregateApplicationBuilder()
                .from(MySource.class)
                .via(MyProcessor.class)
                .to(LogSink.class).build();
        return application.sources(aggregateApp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AggregateApplicationBuilder()
                .from(MySource.class)
                .via(MyProcessor.class)
                .to(LogSink.class)
                .run(args);
    }
}
```

This can run as a standalone jar, however, when deployed to a Tomcat server, the ServletInitializer configure hook cannot accept the configure method return of application.sources(aggregateApp) as the error suggests...

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid source type class org.springframework.cloud.stream.aggregate.AggregateApplicationBuilder
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:146) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:635) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:355) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196) [catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988) [catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860) [catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]

15-Aug-2017 23:21:17.315 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid source type class org.springframework.cloud.stream.aggregate.AggregateApplicationBuilder
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:635)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:355)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

15-Aug-2017 23:21:17.316 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And trying to use the AppClass like...

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(MyAggregateApplication.class);
}
```

does not want to configure the App as an AggregateApplication, does not auto configure the internal message broker and results in this error...

```
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderTypeRegistry]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BinderFactoryConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'binderTypeRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot create binder factory, no `META-INF/spring.binders` resources found on the classpath
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196) [catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988) [catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860) [catalina.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
```

Any suggestions on wiring the AggregateApplication in the ServletInitalizer or disabling the binderRegistry bean to ignore missing binders? Adding rabbitMQ or Kafka binders result in the Processor apps binding to those brokers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it running by providing the aggregate stack with the run() method that returns a ConfigurableApplicationContext, which is allowed as a source. I also had to disable web with web(false) as the embedded tomcat still seemed to want to start...

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(new AggregateApplicationBuilder()
            .web(false)
            .from(MySource.class)
            .via(MyProcessor.class)
            .to(LogSink.class)
            .run(new String[] {}));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `application.sources(aggregateApp)`

The above doesn't seem to be the right thing to do as `AggregateApplicationBuilder` is not a valid source for `SpringApplicationBuilder` as you can only have valid type of `Class`, `Package`, `Resource` and `CharSequence` as sources.